# How do I disable avast notifications?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, notifications, avast

I use Avast 8 on Windows 7. It displays popup alerts all the time. I have disabled the annoying update notification voice alerts, but I'm unable to locate where I can disable the notification popups for the successfully completed updates. I've tried setting the popup duration for zero seconds, as in the image below, but to no avail.

[image]

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to disable notification popups isn't under the "poups" tab, but rather strangely on the "update" tab. Disabling the middle checkbox on the "details" section does the trick.

[image]

Comment: Keeping [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) in mind, can you include a translation of the relevant option text? Or perhaps locate an English language screenshot of the same thing?

Comment: @Karan I removed the offending incident. Sorry.

Comment: No need to apologise, and thanks for uploading English versions of both screenshots.